# Email using SMTP python from gmail account with html body

Tags: python, smtp

I am trying to send email using gmail account from python script using SMTP library. It is working fine with normal message body. But when i try to send it using HTML body. It does not allow me to send.

```
# Import smtplib to provide email functions
import smtplib

# Import the email modules
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# Define email addresses to use
addr_to   = 'xxxx@localdomain.com'
addr_from = "xxxxx@gmail.com"

# Define SMTP email server details
smtp_server = 'smtp.gmail.com'
smtp_user   = 'xxxxxx@gmail.com'
smtp_pass   = 'xxxxxxx'

# Construct email
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['To'] = *emphasized text*addr_to
msg['From'] = addr_from
msg['Subject'] = 'Test Email From RPi'

# Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
text = "This is a test message.\nText and html."
html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>This is a test message.</p>
    <p>Text and HTML</p>
  </body>
</html>
"""

# Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

# Attach parts into message container.
# According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
# the HTML message, is best and preferred.
msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)

# Send the message via an SMTP server
s = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server,587)
s.login(smtp_user,smtp_pass)
s.sendmail(addr_from, addr_to, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

Comment: Can you tell us the error you are getting ?

Comment: it is give "auth" error

Comment: Try turn on  `Allow less secure apps` in your Gmail account which you used to login

Comment: What's up with the `msg['To'] = *emphasized text*addr_to`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add these two lines before attempting to login, it won't gave you the authentication error.

```
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
```

So your code should look like this:

```
    # Import smtplib to provide email functions
    import smtplib

    # Import the email modules
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText

    # Define email addresses to use
    addr_to   = 'xxxx@localdomain.com'
    addr_from = "xxxxx@gmail.com"

    # Define SMTP email server details
    smtp_server = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    smtp_user   = 'xxxxxx@gmail.com'
    smtp_pass   = 'xxxxxxx'

    # Construct email
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['To'] = *emphasized text*addr_to
    msg['From'] = addr_from
    msg['Subject'] = 'Test Email From RPi'

    # Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
    text = "This is a test message.\nText and html."

    (your html code)

    # Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
    part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
    part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

    # Attach parts into message container.
    # According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
    # the HTML message, is best and preferred.
    msg.attach(part1)
    msg.attach(part2)

    # Send the message via an SMTP server
    s = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server,587)
    s.ehlo()
    s.starttls()
    s.login(smtp_user,smtp_pass)
    s.sendmail(addr_from, addr_to, msg.as_string())
    s.quit()
```

Comment: i guess ´s.starttls()´ is enough. no need for s.ehlo()

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be that google [isn't letting using that service anymore as far as i know](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)